# Write own executable format GCC?

Tags: c++, operating-system, executable, elf, binutils

While making OS,  I am compiled my kernel code's into an elf ( https://wiki.osdev.org/ELF ) executable format by linkers and compilers ( gcc or binutils ) and I can load it with my bootloader, I want to make my own custom executable format ( like : https://wiki.osdev.org/PE, ELF, https://wiki.osdev.org/COM ), I have no idea to compile my kernel code's to that file format.

I know how to read a file format ( with its headers and other data ), How  to tell gcc to compile my kernel code's in this file format and how can I instruct linkers and compilers to write that headers into that file?

Comment: This sounds very complicated. What's the point of reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: You'd write new code to add support for your format to [libbfd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library).  It's likely to be a significant amount of work with probably not much payoff compared to using an existing format.

Comment: Perhaps [Tutorial: Creating an LLVM Backend for the Cpu0 Architecture](https://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/elf.html) is a good start. You'd "just" replace ELF with your own format.

Comment: I have a Idea. Just Make a Program that reads elf and convert it to own format with new headers. <- Is this Right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds to me like a viable plan.

Comment: It does indeed sound like a quick way to test some basic features of your format, but I suspect that your format has information that ELF does not have and vice versa (or else you'd probably just use ELF) so for the more complex things you may want to use something like LLVM to create your files from scratch.